# TimeZone Id from GMT offset in Java

Tags: java

I want to get the TimeZone Id of area in java,I have the list of GMT offsets say -3 it should give me ADT.
I am facing really difficulty can anybody help me.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are not well-defined because there are multiple timezones for most offsets. On top of that, three-letter "timezone IDs" should be avoided as well because they're often ambiguous (e.g. [IST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ist) stands for 4 completely different time zones).

The only completely unambiguous timezone IDs are continent/city combinations as used by the [tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), e.g. "Europe/Berlin" or "America/New_York". There's over 400 of them to cover things like daylight savings time and historical changes.

Timezones are much more complex than most people realize.